# Beautiful Soup code to scrape all results and their content page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract information from the url of each of the search results in a web page.
A page has information about companies in a certain location and for each result theres a page with detailed information related to them, like address, company name, unique tax Id and others.

When I run the code, it cannot extract the information of the original page and also I dont know how to enter the link of each one and scrape the detailed information, then pass to the next item and do the same until the last of the results.

Thanks for the help.

My initial code its:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
import urllib3
import xlsxwriter
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = 'https://www.universidadperu.com/empresas/actividades-de-medicos-y-odontologo-categoria.php?dist=1501'
total_added = 0

def make_soup(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request("GET", url)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.data,'lxml')

def main(url):
    global total_added
    db = TinyDB("Universidaddb.json")

    while url:
        print ("Web Page: ", url)
        soup = soup_process(url, db)
        nextlink = soup.find('a', rel=">>>")

        url = False
        if (nextlink):
            url = nextlink['href']

    print ("Added ",total_added)

    make_excel(db)

def soup_process(url, db):
    global total_added

    soup = make_soup(url)
    results1 = soup.find_all("ul")

    #for result1 in results1:
    results = soup.find_all("li")
    for result in results:
        try:
            rec = {
                'webpage': result.find['a'].get('href'),
                'descr': result.a['href'].text
            }

            Result = Query()
            s1 = db.search(Result.webpage == rec["webpage"])

            if not s1:
                total_added += 1
                print ("Adding ... ", total_added)
                db.insert(rec)

        except (AttributeError, KeyError) as ex:
            pass

    return soup

def make_excel(db):
    Headlines = ["Webpage", "Description"]
    row = 0

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Universidad.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.set_column(0,0, 20) # webpage
    worksheet.set_column(1,1, 60) # Descr

    for col, title in enumerate(Headlines):
        worksheet.write(row, col, title)

    for item in db.all():
        row += 1
        worksheet.write(row, 0, item['webpage'], string='Web Page' )
        worksheet.write(row, 1, item['descr'] )

    workbook.close()

main(url)
```